# split up a linear layout background into different colored parts

Tags: java, android, layout, background, styles

For a `ListView`, I want to give the individual `ListView` elements some kind of progress indicator - so to speak, I need a list of progress bars. 
However, each of the listview elements have some text overlay in the form of a `TextView` that should not be affected by the progress bar at all.

I think pictures can tell more than words in this case, so here is pretty much what I want:

[image: background progress bar]

I know I can add "sublayouts" to the individual `LinearLayout`s and change the weight programmatically, which looks somewhat like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@leftSide"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@rightSide"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then programmatically change the weight for both sides (completed and uncompleted):

```
float weightLeft = 0.8f;
float weightRight = 1f-weightLeft;

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLeft = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weightLeft);
LinearLayout left = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftside);
left.setLayoutParams(paramsLeft);

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsRight = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weightRight);
LinearLayout right = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rightside);
left.setLayoutParams(paramsRight);
```

But - the question now is, how do I make the textviews sit on the parent linear layout and ignore the children `LinearLayouts` ?

I can also imagine there is a way to just split up the distribution of the background parts using `drawables`, but I have no clue how to do that, especially not programmatically.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this custom Drawable, mFraction is [0..1]:

```
public class FractionDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float mFraction;

    public FractionDrawable(float fraction) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        setFraction(fraction);
    }

    public void setFraction(float fraction) {
        mFraction = fraction;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect b = getBounds();
        mPaint.setColor(0xff00aa00);
        float x = b.width() * mFraction;
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x, b.height(), mPaint);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffaa0000);
        canvas.drawRect(x, 0, b.width(), b.height(), mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```